# Apache Camel CXF does not find the CXFEndpoint

Tags: java, spring, soap, apache-camel, cxf

**Overview**

I created a camel route class in a spring boot program. This router gets data from a queue, transforms them and then submits the transformed data to the external SOAP webservice.

The RouteClass is as follows:

```
@Component
public class SaleTransactionRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {        
        JacksonDataFormat saleTransactionFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(SaleTransaction.class);

        from(QueueNames.SALETRANSACTION_REQUESTS_QUEUE)
                .routeId("SaleTransactionRoute")
                .unmarshal(saleTransactionFormat)
                .beanRef("saleTransactionTransformer", "prepareSaleTransactionRequest")
                .to(ServiceEndpoints.TMR_WS);            
    }
}
```

The cxf.xml configuration file is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
 http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="tmrSaleTransactionService" address="{{tmr.saletransaction.uri}}"
                     wsdlURL="META-INF/wsdl/TmrSaleTransaction.wsdl"
                     serviceClass="com.sap.xi.WebService.Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="faultOutInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
</beans>
```

The WSDL file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI" targetNamespace="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:Albert"
                  xmlns:p1="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:Albert" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
                  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:documentation/>
    <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI"/>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:IDOC" xmlns="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:IDOC"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:complexType name="E1EDKA1_Partner_Information_Header_DT">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="EN">E1EDKA1 : IDoc: Document Header Partner Information.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/VersionID">2fbeb44e0b4b11e68629000021be3e6e</xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Customer_Number" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">2cdf048ed8f011e5a2620050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PARTN : Partner number</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">d979f388ea5211e5a39c0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>LIFNR : Vendor number at customer location</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Name_1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">2cdf048fd8f011e59c4d0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>NAME1 : Name 1</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Name_2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b97d91b11e5cd270050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>NAME2 : Name 2</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Name_3" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b98d91b11e5aa2b0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>NAME3 : Name 3</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Name_4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b99d91b11e5bf260050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>NAME4 : Name 4</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Street_and_House_Number_1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b9ad91b11e5a7c20050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>STRAS : Street and house number 1</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Street_and_House_Number_2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b9bd91b11e5c23b0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>STRS2 : Street and house number 2</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="PO_Box" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b9cd91b11e59f230050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PFACH : PO Box</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b9dd91b11e5908d0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>ORT01 : City</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Postal_Code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b9ed91b11e5ad580050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PSTLZ : Postal code</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="PO_Box_Postal_Code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60b9fd91b11e5cdb50050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PSTL2 : P.O. Box postal code</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="PO_Box_City" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba0d91b11e5a2210050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PFORT : PO Box city</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Country_Key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba1d91b11e5be1f0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>LAND1 : Country Key</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Contact_Phone_Number_1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba2d91b11e5c1290050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>TELF1 : 1st telephone number of contact person</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Language_Key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba3d91b11e5b9d80050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>SPRAS : Language key</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Form_of_Address" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba4d91b11e5ab5f0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>ANRED : Form of Address</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="District" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba5d91b11e5988a0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>ORT02 : District</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="House_Number" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba6d91b11e5a4a70050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>HAUSN : House number</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Floor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba7d91b11e589d40050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>STOCK : Floor</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Region" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">afd60ba8d91b11e5932c0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>REGIO : Region</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Email_Address" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">c9ab18e3ea5311e58a070050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>ILNNR : Character field up to 70 chars</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ORDER05_Line_item_DT">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="EN">IDoc: Document Item General Data.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/VersionID">0b00fb060dc211e69316000021be3e6e</xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Item_Number" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">646bba06020011e6cd5c0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>POSEX : Item number</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Price_Net" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">8845562ad6b811e58a170050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>VPREI : Price (net)</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Currency" type="xsd:string" default="AUD">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">db2ecd6801fe11e6ba870050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>CURCY : Currency</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Price_Unit" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">8845562bd6b811e592b90050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PEINH : Price unit</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="IDOC_Material_ID" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">3e0dd6f8d92311e5c9c40050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>MATNR : IDOC material ID</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Quantity" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">3e0dd6f9d92311e5892f0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>MENGE : Quantity</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Unit_Of_Measure" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">3e0dd6fad92311e5c79e0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>MENEE : Unit of measure</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="GST_Amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">3e0b9603d92311e596f90050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>GST amount of line</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Quantity_in_Price_Unit" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">91130ff7029611e6b0ef0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>BMNG2 : Quantity in price unit</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Price_Unit_of_Measure" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">91130ff8029611e6caf90050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>PMENE : Price Unit of Measure</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:Albert" xmlns:p5="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:IDOC"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:Albert">
            <xsd:import namespace="urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:IDOC"/>
            <xsd:element name="ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_MT" type="ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_DT"/>
            <xsd:complexType name="ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_DT">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="EN">Albert Commbiz specific ORDER05 creation SOAP message
                    </xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/VersionID">f8c2aec80cf111e6ac2b000021be3e6e</xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Header" type="ORDER05_Albert_Header_DT">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">9bad370b020011e6bc700050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Line_Item" type="p5:ORDER05_Line_item_DT" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">9bad370c020011e697aa0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ORDER05_Albert_Header_DT">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="EN">ORDER05 : IDoc: Document header segment</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/VersionID">73947f000dc211e69b8e000021be3e6e</xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Invoice_Or_Cash_Sale" type="xsd:string" default="Invoice">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">e8961992e9d511e5c3140050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>&quot;Invoice&quot; type Sales Order or &quot;Cash Sale&quot; type Sales
                                Order?
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Transaction_Number" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">7395c8a20dc211e6b9be0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>IDoc document transaction number</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Albert_Site" type="xsd:string" default="0200">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">3beda748e9d711e5b5940050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>Albert site reference</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Delivery_Date">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">d0e06de1d91c11e5c7080050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>DATUM : IDOC: Date</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
                                <xsd:pattern value="CCYY-MM-DD"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Date_of_Creation" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">d0e06de2d91c11e5c9480050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>DATUM : IDOC: Date</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
                                <xsd:pattern value="CCYY-MM-DD"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Invoice_Date" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">d0e06de3d91c11e5ae260050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>DATUM : IDOC: Date</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
                                <xsd:pattern value="CCYY-MM-DD"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Sales_Order_Date" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">d0e06de4d91c11e587bf0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                            <xsd:documentation>DATUM : IDOC: Date</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
                                <xsd:pattern value="CCYY-MM-DD"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Custom_Definition" type="p5:E1EDKA1_Partner_Information_Header_DT">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo source="http://sap.com/xi/TextID">dde650eee9d611e58f1f0050560106d2
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_MT">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_MT" element="p1:ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_MT"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:operation name="Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI"/>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:ORDER05_Albert_SOAP_MT"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="Create_Sales_Order_OB_SIBinding" type="p1:Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
                      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1"
                            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Create_Sales_Order_OB_SIService">
        <wsdl:port name="HTTP_Port" binding="p1:Create_Sales_Order_OB_SIBinding">
            <soap:address
                    location="http://txkci.tmrsap.qgs.qld.gov.au:57600/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=Albert_BC&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI&amp;interfaceNamespace=urn%3Aqss.qld.gov.au%3ATMR_APPL%3AAlbert"
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="HTTPS_Port" binding="p1:Create_Sales_Order_OB_SIBinding">
            <soap:address
                    location="https://txkci.tmrsap.qgs.qld.gov.au:57601/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=Albert_BC&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI&amp;interfaceNamespace=urn%3Aqss.qld.gov.au%3ATMR_APPL%3AAlbert"
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Problem**

When I run the application, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route SaleTransactionRoute at: >>> To[cxf:bean:tmrSaleTransactionService] <<< in route: Route(SaleTransactionRoute)[[From[{{camel.rouge.uri.jms.sale... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:tmrSaleTransactionService due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: tmrSaleTransactionService of type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint
```

I've not found how to tackle this exception yet. So, I'd be grateful if anyone could help me find a solution.

Comment: you haven't defined the bean "tmrSaleTransactionService" in your cxf.xml

Comment: I defined the bean inside cxf.xml but I should let Spring boot know about this bean in startup by importing this resource into Spring boot Application class

Answer (score 1):

I found the missed ring. In cases of dealing with mixed XML and annotation, Spring should be notified about XML beans in order to put them in registry and ultimately finds them when the Spring boot application starts running. In my case, I added @ImportResource to the Spring boot Application class as follows and the problem has been solved:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml")
public class TmrServicesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TmrServicesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```